# What is string::find(char c) supposed to return in C++

Tags: c++, find

What `s.find(c)` supposed to return if char c is not in the string. What I mean is it described anywhere, because c++ documentation usually doesn't say the most important things.

EDIT: More clearly: find returns the index of character we are looking for, what if it(character) is not there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::string::npos`. But it's generally better to use `std::find`, because that returns `s.end()` and iterators are superior to indices.

Comment: find returns the index of character we are looking for, what if it is not there?

Comment: @RobertKilar as the answer says - it returns a value of `std::string::npos`

Answer (score 6):

When the character is not in the string, a special index value `std::string::npos` is returned.

```
size_t index = s.find(c);
if (index == string::npos)
   cout << "not found" << endl;
else
   cout << "found at " << index << endl;
```

More details and examples can be found here:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos

Comment: @jons34yp Thank you, I was not aware of that problem. I have edited my answer and changed the links to point to cppreference.com.